# Mount the nfs volume with windows server

Tags: windows, docker

**Running inside Windows server.**

```
docker volume create --driver local --opt type=nfs --opt o=addr=145.99.63.22,rw --opt device=:/opt/data/softwares nfs-share
```

Getting following issue Error response from daemon:

> create nfs-share: options are not supported on this platform

And I am not able to mount the nfs share inside the windows container.

Answer (score 0):

Yes, you are not able to mount nfs shares inside windows. Even it's in a container.

Comment: I am trying to create the docker volume from smb even docker volume is not working any idea.